# Get currency from setting in device android

Tags: android, react-native

How can I get currency from my android device.

Ex: I set English language then I can get dollar currency. But I live in Singapore, how can the device returns SGD? (Singapore doesn't use dollar).

Ex: Samsung Galaxy J5 use English language
I live in USA -> dollar. 
My friend lives in Singapore -> Singapore dollar

Comment: You can get device info https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info from here and based on device country you can set currency.

That same thing all phone company does if you are apple user and if you buy iPhone from the USA then you are using the phone from India so at the first time it will show USA $ then you need to change store and currency for the specific country.

Same thing you need to for your app

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to getCurrency Symbol , write this method in **Common.java** class

```
public static SortedMap<Currency, Locale> currencyLocaleMap;

static {
    currencyLocaleMap = new TreeMap<Currency, Locale>(new Comparator<Currency>() {
        public int compare(Currency c1, Currency c2) {
            return c1.getCurrencyCode().compareTo(c2.getCurrencyCode());
        }
    });
    for (Locale locale : Locale.getAvailableLocales()) {
        try {
            Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(locale);
            currencyLocaleMap.put(currency, locale);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}


public static String getCurrencySymbol(String currencyCode) {
    Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(currencyCode);
    System.out.println(currencyCode + ":-" + currency.getSymbol(currencyLocaleMap.get(currency)));
    return currency.getSymbol(currencyLocaleMap.get(currency));
}
```

now to get Currency Symbol use this way.

```
    String currencySymbol =Common.getCurrencySymbol(Currency.getInstance(Locale.US).getCurrencyCode());
    String currencySymbol =Common.getCurrencySymbol(Currency.getInstance(Locale.JAPAN).getCurrencyCode());
    String currencySymbol =Common.getCurrencySymbol(Currency.getInstance(Locale.UK).getCurrencyCode());

    //for your case that you want to get Euro symbol because France are with Euro symnol    
    String currencySymbol =Common.getCurrencySymbol(Currency.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE).getCurrencyCode());
    //you can get symbol also if you write string of your desired currency
    String currencySymbol =Common.getCurrencySymbol("INR");
    String currencySymbol = CommonClass.getCurrencySymbol("ZAR");
```

Hope this help.

Comment: My mean, the device uses English language, how to detect its dollar currency when i stay at USA, Singapore dollar when I stay at Singapore

Comment: This returns what you want.

Comment: Nope. The problem comes Locale returned GBP when device use English language. My friend live in Singapore. It's wrong.